# I want to update my data by using updateOne in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am facing some issue in my program.

i create a database in **mongodb** for practice and insert some data by using **mongoose**,
Now i want to update some data by using **.updateOne()** function but its not working for me, even i don't get any error message or something.

I am using
**MongoDB v6.0.1**
**Mongoose v7.0.1**
**Node v18.12.1**

Even i try on MongoDB shell but their also not working, i don't know what to do now.

**This is my app.js code**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB');

// First Data Collection
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : [true, "Please check your data entry, no name specified"]
    },
    rating : {
        type : Number,
        min : 1,
        max : 10
    },
    review : String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    // Validation require
    name : "Pineapple",
    rating : 5,
    review : "This is the best fruit"
});

// fruit.save();

Fruit.updateOne({_id:"6413227328c4dbee8166933c"},{review:"This is the best fruits"})
```

**And this is my data collections**

```
> use fruitsDB
switched to db fruitsDB
> db.fruits.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6413222a13b4de0491c61b7d"), "name" : "Pineapple", "rating" : 5, "review" : "This is the best fruit", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6413227328c4dbee8166933b"), "name" : "Kiwi", "rating" : 8, "review" : "Good", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6413227328c4dbee8166933d"), "name" : "Banana", "rating" : 8, "review" : "Good", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6413227328c4dbee8166933c"), "name" : "Orange", "rating" : 8, "review" : "Good", "__v" : 0 }
>
```

When i am trying to print all the data using **.find()** then this method is also not working for me, so later i use **.then()** method, and now it's working.

```
Fruit.find().then(function(list){
    list.forEach((ele) => {
        console.log(ele.name)
    });
    mongoose.connection.close();
})
```

But **.updateOne()** is still not working i try many ways, Or i'm doing some mistakes.
Please help me to understand that what mistake i did and where.
Thank You!!

I want to **update** my data by using **mongoose**

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you:
Ex: update kiwi rating to 9

```
Fruit.updateOne({_id: "64e656a63afff4b4935da8a7"}, {$set: {rating: 
9}}).exec().then(() => {
    console.log("Fruit updated succesfully");
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error("Error updating fruit: ", err);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).